# Element type invalid when adding button

Tags: react-native

I was following React Native basic tutorial. Then after it ended, I tried to add a button in the code used in [TextInput tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input.html), following example in [Button page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, Button, View } from 'react-native';

class AwsumProjek extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {tiText: ''};
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <View style={{padding: 10}}>
              <TextInput
                style={{height: 40}}
                placeholder="Type here to translate!"
                onChangeText={(tiText) => this.setState({tiText})}
              />
              <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
                {this.state.tiText.split(' ').map((word) => word && 'WA').join(' ')}
              </Text>
              <Button
                title="Press Purple"
                color="#841584"
                accessibilityLabel="Learn more about purple"
              />
           </View>
        );
      }
    }

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwsumProjek', () => AwsumProjek);
```

Instead I got this error

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
Check the render method of 'AwsumProjek'.
```

What did I do wrong? Seeing other answer, is it something related to importing something?

I'm native android developer trying to learn React Native, and as me now, Javascript is totally unfamiliar for me.

Comment: Are you using React Native version 0.37? Button was introduced in 0.37

Comment: Ooo rite I still use 0.36! Thanks! Can you please make it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using correct version of React Native. `Button` component was introduced in React Native version 0.37